# Does PuLP have a function that outputs the Lagrangian multipliers at a particular solution?

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, pulp

I remember when using the *linprog* function in MATLAB, one of the outputs is a structure containing the Lagrange multipliers at the solution "x" (separated by constraint type).

Right now I'm programming in Python and using PuLP to solve a linear optimization problem.  I am using the PULP_CBC_CMD solver.  Does PuLP have an equivalent function that will return the Lagrange multipliers at my optimal solution?

I've looked on the internet quite a bit and haven't really found any documentation on this.

Answer (score 1):

For the constraints, PuLP can provide the **duals**:

```
  con.pi
```

and for the variables, we have **reduced costs**:

```
  x.dj
```

Together these form the Lagrangian multipliers.

E.g. you can do something like:

```
for (id,c) in lpProb.constraints.items():
    print(id,c.pi)
for v in lpProb.variables():
    print(v.name,v.dj)
```